# why the list returned from the API deployed alphabetically?

Tags: c#, list, api

I am using an C# API to return Contest datas.I have a List and returning this  as Output from API.

[image: API Output]

API Url :[API Url](http://52.70.18.77:84/api/News/Contest/GetContestDetails?ContestId=1)

In this output the List is sorted in Alphabetical order.I want the List in the below mentioned Contest class order ,without sorting.

Contest Class:

```
public class Contest
{
    public int ContestID { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public string MovieImage { get; set; }
    public string RegionalMovieName{get;set;}
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer1 { get; set; }
    public string Answer2 { get; set; }
    public string Answer3 { get; set; }
    public string Ad1ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Ad2ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Ad3ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string AdText { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Using the above class in Output List.

Controller Code:

```
public class ContestController : ApiController
{
    MMProvider.ContestProvider Provider = new MMProvider.ContestProvider();
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetContestDetails")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetContestDetail(string ContestId)
    {
        Contest _contest = new Contest();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContestId.ToString()))
        {
            List<Contest> ContestDetailsList = Provider.GetContestDetail(ContestId);
                return Ok(ContestDetailsList);
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

}

StoredProcedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_GetMblContest] 
@ContestID INT
AS
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(ContestID) FROM  Mbl_Contest WHERE ContestID = @ContestID AND Status='A')
BEGIN
    SELECT ContestID,MovieName,RegionalLanguage,MovieImage,Ad1ImageUrl,Ad2ImageUrl,Ad3ImageUrl,AdText,Question,Answer1,Answer2,Answer3,StartDate,EndDate FROM Mbl_Contest WHERE ContestID = @ContestID 
END
END
```

Comment: What do you want us to do? Guess?

Comment: What order do you want then? Sort it accordingly. You want it to be random? Shuffle it then.

Comment: I want it in the ''Contest'' class order

Comment: The code will automatically put data into your class.  You do not have to do anything.  If you are seeing the data in alphabetical order it is just that VS displays class properties alphabetically even though you class structure is not alphabetical.

Comment: Is it possible to display the  result as per the class order?

Comment: I still wonder how you expect anyone to solve the problem, when you don't even add the code that generates the result. And replace the image by the actual XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "class order". Class members *exist* without any internal order, no matter what order you type them in.

Assuming you are using the [default serializers for WebApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization), you need to specify which order you want:

```
[DataContract]
public class Contest
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public int ContestID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string MovieName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string MovieImage { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string RegionalMovieName{get;set;}

    // ... the pattern should be clear
}
```